# ajax not working with full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have used [full calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/demos/external-dragging.html)  external dragging events for a topic assigning interface.Used ajax for updating the topic details to mysql db but ajax is not working.I am not getting the values in my controller.Checked the other questions here but didn't find a solution.Can any one help?

```
<link href='assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='assets/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script src='assets/js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='assets/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
 <script src='assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'>  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });

/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        drop: function(date,event) {


          // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?

                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }
             $.ajax({
               url: '/addSchedule',
               dataType: 'json',
               type: 'post',
               data: {event: event},                  
               success: function(response){
                  console.log('response');
               }
             });

      }     

    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: `it's not working` is not a proper problem statement. What's not working and what troubleshooting steps have you followed?

Comment: @charlietfl used ajax to save the event details when a drop event occurs on full calendar,but ajax call failed. i am not getting the values in controller

Comment: @AVM, do you see an error in your console? Also, if you add `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR)}` ([see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to your $ajax call, do you see an error message?

Comment: @milz no,tried error:function() also but i am not getting an error in console.

Comment: @AVM There are a number of things that can go wrong with the ajax request and it will be quite difficult to remote debug. A few things you can try: Does the request reaches the server? If you use `die('something')`, do you see "something" in the request response? Are you using `$_POST` in the server method? Are you returning a json object from the server? Do you see your `response` (from the success method) in the console?

Comment: @milz actually the request is not happening,i am using $_POST and returning json objects.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue as @AVM, by using the same procedure he is using.

What I can say is ass soon as the code reaches the AJAX call it "stops working", or does not even consider it. Also when the event is dropped into the calendar the calendar sort of freezes....

I also tried putting the ajax call in a function and calling it passing the required parameters with no success.

Also what ever I put in either the success and error functions noting gets executed.

Thanks MAt

Comment: Something worth highlighting in the Google Chrome console I am getting the following error when I set a breaking point at the very beginning of the ajax call:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue as @AVM, by using the same procedure he is using.

this is the solution to this problem:

```
        var event_title = event.title;
        var event_date = event._start.format();
        var event_backgroundColor = event.backgroundColor;
        var event_borderColor = event.borderColor;

        $.ajax({
            url: '../php/add_event.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                title: event_title,
                date: event_date,
                backgroundColor: event_backgroundColor,
                borderColor: event_borderColor
            },
            success: function(response){
              alert(response);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

Note the:

```
 var event_date = event._start.format();
```

This solved my problem, I hope it will solve yours.

Thanks
Mat